# How to convert Date format to `2019-04-24T04:27:14.867Z`

Tags: javascript, string, date, object

I need to send a Date to my backend in the following format:

```
2019-04-24T04:27:14.867Z
```

I tried doing these:

```
var d = new Date();
console.log(d);

var utcDate1 = new Date(Date.UTC(96, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5));

console.log(utcDate1);

var newFormat = new Date('04/21/19');

console.log(newFormat);
```

Nothing works. what is the correct approach to get the value as like I requried.

[Live Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/yozb1cjf/).

Comment: use `toISOString()` on date

Answer (score 3):

You can use `.toISOString()` method to get that format. [Refer](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_toisostring.asp)

```js
var newFormat = new Date('04/21/2019');
console.log(newFormat.toISOString());
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use inbuilt function `toISOString()` [Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString)

The `toISOString()` method returns a string in simplified extended ISO format

```js
var d = new Date();
console.log(d);

var utcDate1 = new Date();

console.log(utcDate1.toISOString());
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the in-built [`toISOString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) method:

```js
var newFormat = new Date('04/21/19').toISOString();

console.log(newFormat);
```